Как автоматически удалять кеш с конкретного сайта, или отключить его кеширование?
Я выступаю в роли пользователя, а не владельца сайта! Есть сайт https://journal.top-academy.ru . При каждом его использовании он что то делает с кешом, что при повторном его открытии показывается просто белый лист, пока не очистить кеш. Можно ли как то в браузере Firefox автоматически очищать кеш конкретно этого сайта, а не всего браузера, при закрытии. Или можно как то отключить кеширование этого сайта вообще, если есть такая возможность. Я в этой теме не особо разбираюсь.
P.S. Ранее пытались обратиться к "Владельцам" сайта, с просьбой решить эту проблему. Нас послали в хром, т.к. там он безотказно работает, и "сайт чинить не собираемся и вообще это у вас проблемы а не у сайта".

@Dev18 Спасибо большое! Все работает как и надо)

Установите это расширение для Firefox, чтобы настроить автоматическую очистку кэша.
Добавьте сайт journal.top-academy.ru в разделе «Правила», и при закрытии браузера кэш для этого сайта будет автоматически очищаться.
